# Can't get newest why3 version from opam

Tags: ocaml, opam

I am using Linux Slackware 14.2, opam version 1.2.2, ocaml 4.03.0 and wanted to install [why3 module](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/why3/why3.1.2.0/). As far as I can see in the Internet, the last version of why3 package is 1.2.0.

But even after I ran

```
opam update
```

It still suggests my to install why3 1.0.0.

1. What should I do to update the packages list?
2. How can I install why3 module system wide as root? Is it safe enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your opam and ocaml installations are both seriously out of date. The latest version of OCaml is 4.07.1, and the latest version of opam is 2.0.4. Linux distro repositories are unfortunately often not very up to date, and as I understand it, packages published for opam v2 aren't backwards-compatible with opam v1.x.

Try installing the latest opam by following [the installation guide](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html). Then, using opam, install a more recent version of OCaml and you should be able to get the latest version of why3.

It's recommended to manage your OCaml installations and associated packages with opam instead of installing them globally, since that can potentially cause an unruly mess of broken dependencies over time.

Comment: Is it possible to install using my current ocaml: newer requires glibc update which is hard to do.

Comment: Current OCaml should be fine. You can switch to the system compiler with opam, and latest why3 depends on >4.02.3, so 4.03 should be fine. But I'm pretty sure you'll have to update opam at least.

Comment: I ran the command `opam update`, but it didn't update the packages list.

Comment: No, you have to update your opam installation to v2.x at least