# Opam could install latest package and told 'Already up-to-date'?

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune

I wanna use `opam` to install `dune` package whose version is [`1.11.0`](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/dune/dune.1.11.0/) or higher. But it told me `Already up-to-date` while `dune` is still `1.2.1`.

pasting my operations:

```
$ opam update

=-=- Updating package repositories =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org/1.2.2
```

And then:

```
$ opam upgrade dune
Already up-to-date.
```

But `dune` didn't be upgraded.. It's still `1.2.1`.. How can I install higher version I wanted?

- `opam --version` is `1.2.2`
- `dune --version` is `1.2.1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get newest why3 version from opam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328507/cant-get-newest-why3-version-from-opam)

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this phrase

```
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org/1.2.2
                                                  ^^^^^^
```

The 1.2.2 version of opam is long ago deprecated and is never updated, so you can't get anything new. You shall [install opam 2.0](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html) to get access to the newest packages.